# Constructing a Multivariate Probability Distribution Formula

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

Suppose there are three individuals playing a simple game, Player $1$, Player $2$, and Player $3$.

In each round of the game, one of the players is uniformly randomly selected to receive the point for that round.  The game ends when any player achieves a score of $10$ points.

How can a multivariate probability distribution formula be constructed that would express the probability of each possible combination of the total number of rounds a game will contain, and an arbitrarily chosen player's (i.e., Player $1$'s) score at the end of the game?  How does this formula change if we introduce the assumption that the arbitrarily chosen player did not win the game?

I started by noting that the chosen player has a $\frac{1}{3}$ probability of winning each round.  I think that for a fixed number of rounds $n$, the formula would be the binomial distribution ${n \choose a} (\frac{1}{3})^a (\frac{2}{3})^{1 - a}$, where by plugging a possible point score into $a$ one obtains the probability of the chosen player attaining that exact point score, but I'm not sure if this is right or where to go from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To calculate the probability of the game ending on a particular score $k-j-10$, you need the score to reach $k-j-9$ in any order of scoring, and then the particular player to have the final score.

As saulsplatz has said in effect, the probability that the final score is $k - j - 10$ is $$\frac{(k+j+9)!}{k!\,j!\, 9!}\left(\frac13\right)^{k+j+10}$$ with $j$ and $k < 10$, though note that $j - k -10$ is also possible $($if $k \not=j)$ with the same probability, as are $k - 10 -j$ and $j-10-k$ and $10 -k-j$ and $10-j-k$, so the overall probability of that pattern is $6$ times that expression if $k \not=j$ and $3$ times that expression if $k=j$.

So the probabilities for individual scores are (with a total of $\frac13$ since we have assumed a particular player wins)

```
    j   0       1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9
k                                               
0       0.00002 0.00006 0.00010 0.00014 0.00015 0.00014 0.00012 0.00009 0.00006 0.00004
1       0.00006 0.00021 0.00041 0.00060 0.00070 0.00070 0.00062 0.00050 0.00038 0.00026
2       0.00010 0.00041 0.00090 0.00140 0.00174 0.00186 0.00176 0.00151 0.00119 0.00088
3       0.00014 0.00060 0.00140 0.00233 0.00310 0.00351 0.00351 0.00318 0.00265 0.00206
4       0.00015 0.00070 0.00174 0.00310 0.00439 0.00527 0.00556 0.00530 0.00464 0.00378
5       0.00014 0.00070 0.00186 0.00351 0.00527 0.00668 0.00742 0.00742 0.00680 0.00579
6       0.00012 0.00062 0.00176 0.00351 0.00556 0.00742 0.00865 0.00907 0.00869 0.00772
7       0.00009 0.00050 0.00151 0.00318 0.00530 0.00742 0.00907 0.00993 0.00993 0.00919
8       0.00006 0.00038 0.00119 0.00265 0.00464 0.00680 0.00869 0.00993 0.01034 0.00996
9       0.00004 0.00026 0.00088 0.00206 0.00378 0.00579 0.00772 0.00919 0.00996 0.00996
```

and the probability of a pattern is (with a total of $1$, since we do not care who wins or comes second)

```
    j   0       1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9
k                                               
0       0.00005                                 
1       0.00034 0.00062                             
2       0.00062 0.00248 0.00269                         
3       0.00083 0.00359 0.00837 0.00698                     
4       0.00090 0.00419 0.01046 0.01860 0.01318                 
5       0.00084 0.00419 0.01116 0.02108 0.03163 0.02003             
6       0.00070 0.00372 0.01054 0.02108 0.03338 0.04451 0.02596         
7       0.00053 0.00301 0.00904 0.01908 0.03179 0.04451 0.05440 0.02979     
8       0.00038 0.00226 0.00715 0.01590 0.02782 0.04080 0.05213 0.05958 0.03103 
9       0.00025 0.00159 0.00530 0.01236 0.02267 0.03476 0.04634 0.05517 0.05977 0.02988
```

and the probability that a game lasts a particular number of rounds is $($adding up to $1)$

```
10  0.00005
11  0.00034
12  0.00124
13  0.00331
14  0.00718
15  0.01339
16  0.02232
17  0.03402
18  0.04819
19  0.06425
20  0.08123
21  0.09750
22  0.11066
23  0.11787
24  0.11668
25  0.10592
26  0.08620
27  0.05977
28  0.02988
```

This means that

- the equally most likely individual final scores are $10-8-8$ or $8-10-8$ or $8-10-8$, each with a probability of about $0.01034$,
- the most likely final pattern is $10-9-8$ with a combined probability of about $0.05977$, and
- the most likely number of rounds in the game is $23$ with a combined probability of $0.11787$.  The expected number of rounds is about $22.34469$ and the median also $23$, all rather less than the $27$ or $28$ involved in the most likely scores.

The expected final score per player is about $7.44823$, also rather less than the most likely scores might suggest.

Answer (score 2):

That's the correct formula for the probability that a specified play scores exactly $a$ points in $n$ rounds, but I see that it helps you much.

If a specified player wins, then he scores $10$ points and each of the others scores at most $9$ (so $10\leq n\leq 28)$.  So the probability that he wins is
$$\frac13\sum_{k=0}^9\sum_{j=0}^9\binom{k+j+9}{k,j,9}\left(\frac13\right)^{k+j+9}$$ because the winning toss, when the specified player gets his tenth point, must be the last one.

Now you just have to modify this formula to account for the fact that the game lasts $n$ rounds, that is $k+j+10=n$.

Comment: Without even doing the calculation, that expression must be $\frac13$ by symmetry as each player is equally likely to win.

Comment: @Henry Sure, but the question includes the requirement that the game ends in $n$ rounds, and I'm trying to show the OP how to get there.  That's what the last sentence is about.